# react-hook-form multi step form issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I'm working on implementation of a multi step form with `react-hook-form` and my problem is that input fields do not get reinitialized with the form data when I return to the previous page.

I'm using `<FormProvider />` component from `react-hook-form` to inject the form data into  the pages and my `input` components are registered with `register` method from `useFormContext()` hook

```
const CreateAccount = () => {
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);

  const methods = useForm<FormData>({
    mode: "onChange",
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  const handleNextStep = () => {
    if (currentStep >= 5) return;
    setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1);
  };
  const handlePreviousStep = () => {
    if (currentStep <= 0) return;
    setCurrentStep(currentStep - 1);
  };

  const renderContent = () => ({
    [RegistrationSteps.UsernameEmail]: <UsernameEmail handleNextStep={handleNextStep} handlePreviousStep={handlePreviousStep} />,
    [RegistrationSteps.Password]: <CreatePassword handleNextStep={handleNextStep} handlePreviousStep={handlePreviousStep} />,
  });

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm">
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            {renderContent()[currentStep]}
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CreateAccount;
```

Here is what the input fields look like

```
 const {
    register
  } = useFormContext();


    <TextField
      label="Email"
       {...register("email")}
     />
```

Even though the form still holds the data in its state, it does not populate into corresponding fields when I switch back and forth between the form pages.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a single form at a global level, I recommend creating each component in your step as a form with its own instance of `useForm()` and wrapping steps in a state provider to store data across different steps. That way, you can assign values to the step forms from the respective state using `defaultValues` option of `useForm` on initialization.

- You can check out [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-9pg6j?file=/src/index.js) for the basic architecture that I'm trying to explain.
- [defaultValues in useForm](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform)